# What SQL query to search attributes in JSON data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Here is JSON data in a database column named "debts":

```
{  
   "debt_block_1":{  
      "debt_type_1":"House",
      "repayment_frequency_1":"Monthly",
      "financial_institution_1":"anz",
      "repayment_amount_1":"899",
      "amount_your_share_1":"98",
      "loan_term_1":"3",
      "rate_1":"3"
   },
   "debt_block_2":{  
      "debt_type_2":"Creditcard",
      "repayment_frequency_2":"Monthly",
      "financial_institution_2":"anz",
      "credit_limit_2":"2000",
      "remaining_balance_2":"200"
   },
   "special_notes":""
}
```

Here, I need to get debt types if financial institution is "anz". I have no experience with writing SQL queries for JSON data types.

I tried the following query:

```
select JSON_SEARCH(debts, 'all' , 'anz') from table_name;
```

and the result of the query is given below:

```
["$.debt_block_1.financial_institution_1", "$.debt...
```

**Editing start**

Another query I executed is

```
SELECT  debts, JSON_EXTRACT(debts, "$.debt_type")
     FROM application_data
     WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(debts, "$.financial_institution") = 'anz'
```

No result.

**Editing end**

Any suggestions on how I could get the `debt_type` value where  `financial_institution ="anz"`?

Comment: I'd recommend you to modify the json doc first before SQL it..... e.g. adding another key "debt_type" & "financial_institution" and copy the value for each segment.

Comment: The following [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1a84013c230e99186a75136b919fb738) can give you some ideas. The example is in MariaDB 10.2.12 but MySQL >= 8.0.4 should work.

Comment: @wchiquito  Thank you for your time , just wondering what is the purpose of '^\\[|\\]$  in query,

Comment: Basically create the correct syntax for the [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function.

Comment: Is there any way to write it for mysql 5.7   @wchiquito

Comment: You can replace [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function with other functions, for example: [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) or [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), see [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=03545eaa11d1f38f6238cb1841a88ff0). Don't forget to evaluate performance problems, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You would have an easier time finding the desired records if you were able to use JSON_CONATINS looking for 'finanical_instituion'.  But having 'financial_instituion_1', 'financial_instituiton_2' means you have to search for all of those variants.

Comment: if i change the structure and keep financial_institution name for all records then could you please suggest query to find 'debt_type' against financial institution as JSON_CONTAINS would find path of element